# Flaky Internet on windows when Linux (on same machine) is rock solid

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, network-adapter

I've been dealing with this issue for over a month now. I'll list everything I've tried but feel free to ask for additional information or logs and I can track them down. (I am a software engineer and have solid computer knowledge but networking is a weak point for me).

**So here's the problem:**
I have my machine set up with a dual boot for Windows 10 and Linux (mint). On Linux I get about 800Mb/s down AND up. **On Windows (remember same physical machine) I get about 600Mb/s down(initial download seems strong but then it falls off to '0' pulling down the average) and 0-1.5Mb/s up**. On Windows I have to refresh internet pages multiple times before a page will load (the connectivity seems to come and go in waves because a page will partial load and then seem to freeze). On YouTube especially it will often report that I don't have an internet connection at all and I have to refresh a few times before a video will decide to load.

**My Environment:**

- Cat6a cable from my network switch to my motherboard
- Motherboard/NIC: Asus Prime X470 (integrated intel 1Gb NIC)
- Router: G3100 (Verizon Fios)

  - Running (cat5e?)cable from port #4 to my network switch - *NETGEAR 8-Port Gigabit Ethernet Plus Switch* (GS108Ev3)
- Modem: don't know off the top of my head but if it's important I can grab the model number.
- CPU: Ryzen 3600x
- RAM: 32GB
- SSD: 512GB Samsung Evo 970

**What I've Tried So far**

1. Installed Chipset drivers for my motherboard from ASUS x470 product support page
2. Installed Intel Lan drivers from motherboard support page
3. Disabled Windows 10 Firewall completely and reran speed test (I have it renabled now)
4. Checked that my "network profile" on windows is set to 'private' not 'public' network.
5. Manually assigned a new local ipv4 address with googles 8.8.8.8 DNS server specified.
6. Ran windows updater and installed all available updates
7. **Using a wifi adapter I get a slower but much more stable 298Mb/s Down / 230Mb/s Up**

**Suspisions...**
I did notice that when on ethernet my router recongnizes my computer (running windows) as the same machine as the linux machine ("desktop-mint" in the devices list in my router). BUT when I use a wifi adapter, my windows computer is STILL ASSIGNED THE SAME LOCAL IPv4 ADDRESS BUT, it is recognized by my router as "DESKTOP-3RELKQ5" (which is my windows machine).

This may be the root of the problem? I'm not sure... and if it is, idk how to fix it?

Anyway, I'm open to any suggestions. Thanks!

Update: I've since upgraded to Windows 11 and the issue still persists.

Comment: I would try the latest Intel driver, not the old one from Asus.

Comment: Just gave that a shot but unfortunately same results :( - 709.5 Down 0.79 Up

Comment: What are the network interfaces MTU settongs under each OS?

Comment: Windows is set to 1500
Switching over to linux now to check

Comment: Linux is also 1500

Comment: You might try a Windows traffic monitoring utility such as GlassWire, https://www.glasswire.com/, to see what connections Windows is opening. Is it spending a lot of time checking data with Defender? Are there Windows apps running in the background, such as weather or news? Perhaps even malware? A traffic monitor will eliminate those as possible causes of the issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Okay, so I reinistalled Windows... no dice. I ran Glasswire to monitor my network activity. Didn't see anything out of the ordinary there either. I reset all my firewall settings (though I don't think I ever changed them). I also googled my exact NIC that's listed in device manager and grabbed the driver directly from intel.

I'm still suspect of my router treating my windows and linux installs as the same machine (even though I guess they technically are the same cause the MAC address is the same).

Comment: I'm so baffled... I set up a windows vm inside my windows host machine with both a NAT configuration and then again as a 'bridged adapter'. In both cases the VM got about 700Mb/s down and 300+Mb/s up. When the host machine is getting < 1.0Mb/s up...

Comment: The VM guest makes things highly suspicious. It's difficult giving concrete advice without seeing the specific behavior. How does LAN behave? Traffic that doesn't leave your own network? You could test with your phone if you have no other machine available. You could try a VPN too - the expected result would be low speeds, but an opposite outcome could prove interesting.

Comment: Oh that's a good idea. I can try some file transfers later between some machines in my house. I'll let you know!